# Mapping values to case class in json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

Say I have the following:

```
[ {
    "job_id": "1",
    "status": "running"
  },
  {
    "job_id": "0",
    "status": "finished"
  }]
```

Could I somehow do the following with json4s:

```
case class Job(job_id: Int, status: JobStatus)

abstract class JobStatus

case class JobFinished extends JobStatus

case class JobRunning extends JobStatus

... some  magic is probably needed here
```

Such that extracting the first snippet would result in:

```
[ Job(1, JobRunning()), Job(0, JobFinished())]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @Andres Neumann's answer is pretty good  it does require reimplementing the serialization of the whole Job class (which might be a lot larger than the dumbed-down Job class in the example), whereas the only serialization which is actually needed is for the status. Based on @Andreas' answer the actual code needed is somewhat shorter and does not require every field in the Job to be serialized manually.

```
// here is the "magic" a custom serializer
class JobStatusSerializer extends CustomSerializer[JobStatus](format => (
  // unmarshal Function
  {
    case JString(status) => {
      // helper functions, could be improved by having a mapping
      def stringToJobStatus(in: String): JobStatus = in match {
        case "running" => JobRunning
        case "finished" => JobFinished
      }

      stringToJobStatus(status)
    }
  },
  // marshal Function
  {

    case status: JobStatus => {
      def jobStatusToString(jobStatus: JobStatus): String = jobStatus match {
        case JobRunning => "running"
        case JobFinished => "finished"

      }

      JString(jobStatusToString(status))
    }
  }
  )
)
```

Comment: Nice one :) Good I could help. I like the shorter solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best way of creating a scala case class based on the JSON, is using this site, this add the magic, I normally use this site, you can even change the name of the clases so in your case, you can use the site and then manage the relations within classes:

[JSON to Scala](http://json2caseclass.cleverapps.io/)

[image: JSON PASTE]

[image: RESULT]

Comment: With this approach you would loose all type safety.

Comment: @AndreasNeumann is indeed pointing out the downside of this; I would like to retain type-safety, in this case that means having a dedicated type for the job's status.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an enum and add `EnumSerializer` to your `formats` through json4s-ext.
However, your enum would be serialized as an int (0 or 1 in your case).

Adding to my own answer, you can also use EnumNameSerializer which would serialize to the enum values you specified (like "running" or "finished").

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but needs some coding.
I will try to break it down in some smaller steps.

## Defintion of types / model

```
// Types
case class Job(jobId: Int, status: JobStatus)
// Sealed trait to make match exhaustive in helper functions
sealed trait JobStatus
// use case object to not create uneeded instances, also case class without () no longer allowed
case object JobFinished extends JobStatus
case object JobRunning extends JobStatus
```

## The "magic"

### Needed imports

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.Serialization
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.{read, write}
```

### Helper Functions

```
// helper functions, could be improved by having a mapping
implicit def stringToJobStatus(in: String) : JobStatus = in match {
  case "running" => JobRunning
  case "finished" => JobFinished
}
implicit def jobStatusToString(jobStatus: JobStatus) : String = jobStatus match {
  case  JobRunning => "running"
  case  JobFinished => "finished"
}
```

## Custom Serializer

```
// here is the "magic" a custom serializer
class JobSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Job](format => (
         // unmarshal Function
         {
           case JObject( JField("job_id", JString(jobId)) :: JField("status", JString(status)) :: Nil ) => {
             new Job(jobId.toInt, status)
           }
         },
         // masrshal Function
         {
           case Job(jobId, status) => JObject(
         JField("job_id", JString(jobId.toString)) :: 
         JField("status", JString(status)) :: Nil)
         }
))
```

### make Serializer acessible

```
// Implicit formats for serialization and deserialization
implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) + new JobSerializer
```

## Example in REPL

```
val data = """
[
 {
   "job_id": "1",
   "status": "running"
 },
 {
   "job_id": "0",
   "status": "finished"
 }
]
"""

read[List[Job]](data)

res3: List[Job] = List(Job(1,JobRunning), Job(0,JobFinished))
```

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me out. Though I've found a shorter way, see my answer.